# More complex Flex layout

Tags: google-chrome, css, flexbox

**Only trying to achieve this layout in chrome**.
The names in layout are its classes, so you have a bit less confusing orientation in there
This is the layout I would like to use:

```
(The "nothing changed" part is the one with class "info")

|------------------------------|
|                              |
|           header             |
|------------------------------|
|      |                       |
|      |        info           |
|      |-----------------------|
|      |      |                |
|      |      |                |
| nav  |      |                |
|      | menu |     main       |
|      |      |                |
|      |      |                |
|      |      |                |
|------|------|----------------|
```

Link to existing example with a bit messed layout. I am trying to 
http://codepen.io/Akxe/pen/chIzx

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? And what do you want it to do differently? A screenshot with the problem area highlighted would be helpful, or a thorough description of what's going wrong.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91817349/Sn%C3%ADmek%20obrazovky%20(12).jpg
The red flexbox is meant to be in position of green rectangle. And the two other should resize adequately. (The mos left is navbar and don't resize.) 
PS: there is a link to codepen there is the code and the example live.

Comment: There's a *lot* of code in that pen, could you whittle it down to only the relevant portions?

Comment: @cimmanon: Simplified version of the demo (and added a missing `<ul>` tag in `.nav`): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/atoFB

Comment: All 5 of the elements in the diagram are siblings in your code, which makes this impossible.  In order to get a layout like that, the elements have to be grouped like this:  (header, nav, (info, menu, main)).  I realize your ultimate goal is to have main appear before/after header (which is likely why they are siblings in the first place), but this simply not possible.

Comment: Are you saying then that I need to add another flex for those tree?

Comment: You need some sort of container to hold the info, menu, main elements.

Comment: Also worth noting, using only 2 containers limits your browser support to only those who support wrapping (IE10, Chrome, Opera).  Grouping like this would maximize your browser support but limit how you can reorder them: (header, (nav, (info, (menu, main)))).

Comment: Well I actually decided to move the info away from flex, so I can destroy the element after a few seconds. Any ideas? I have no clue how to stop considering element as flex item

Comment: Made it. Thanks a lot to everyone

Comment: can you post a code pen? I want to see the final result D:

Comment: http://codepen.io/Akxe/pen/chIzx This is it (copy of my page I didnt actually did it on codepen)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is too large to understand, so I simply started from scratch and made a simple template

Here is my pen: http://codepen.io/chaitan94/pen/vFgek

I made all the widths using percentages, so its a basic fluid template.
Hope this helps!